# Change from frontend area to adminhtml area

Tags: magento2, state, area

I try to use an email template which located in adminhtml area from frontend, the problem is i dont know if changing the state area code is the right way because i alway got an error by doing like this:

```
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $area = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
      $currentAreaCode = $area->getAreaCode();
      $area->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
```

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Area code is already
>   set

Answer (score 2):

That’s because of the following guard clause

```
#File: vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php
public function setAreaCode($code)
{
    if (isset($this->_areaCode)) {
        throw new MagentoFrameworkExceptionLocalizedException(
            new MagentoFrameworkPhrase('Area code is already set')
        );
    }
    $this->_configScope->setCurrentScope($code);
    $this->_areaCode = $code;
}
```

The \Magento\Framework\App\State object will only let you set a value **once**.

**Solution:** By catching the exception Magento throws and silently ignoring it.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
    $name=null
) {
    try {
        $appState-->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
    } catch (MagentoFrameworkExceptionLocalizedException $e) {
        // intentionally left empty
    }
    parent::__construct($name);
}
```

Or As per your code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$area = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
if (!$area->getAreaCode()) {
    $area->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
}
$currentAreaCode = $area->getAreaCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to emulate `adminhtml` area code by using `emulateAreaCode` from `Magento\Framework\App\State` . Check this class implementation as reference: `Magento\Widget\Controller\Adminhtml\Widget\Instance\Blocks`. I think it's a better solution than just silently ignoring the exception.